# Rogue Broadcast intents being sent

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I have implemented receiving broadcast intents in my published app, actually sending them will be done in the near future. However, intents are already received and it crashes expectedly because mandatory Bundle extras are missing. After seeing this crash I wanted to use `LocalBroadcastManager`, but now the question is if this is good practice.

The `BroadcastReceiver` is not registered in the Manifest, but it is in the `Application` class:

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerReceiver(NotificationBroadcastReceiver(), IntentFilter("com.me.my_app.REUPLOAD_REQUESTED.open_notification"))
    }
}
```

Now, I received this crash in Crashlytics for a single user, 25 times in an hour:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.me.my_app.REUPLOAD_REQUESTED.open_notification flg=0x10 pkg=com.me.my_app (has extras) } in d.a.a.a.v.b.a@41e45b2
```

What or who is sending these intents then? Could it be done by the user itself?

**Use `LocalBroadcastManager` or not**

My app has 4 modules: one that contains `Application` and some Dagger modules, and a separate module for the data/domain/presentation layer. The reason to use broadcasts, is because there are 2 loosely coupled components: 
In the data layer `FirebaseMessagingService` receives a FCM message which in response sends an Intent to `NotificationBroadcastReceiver`, which is responsible for showing a notification and handle interaction with that notification.

Should LocalBroadcastManager be used? This is not actual IPC, it's just a singleton holding a list of BroadcastReceivers. It's packaged within androidx and at the moment not labeled as deprecated.

If not, what should be used?

Answer (score 1):

> After seeing this crash I'll use LocalBroadcastManager

`LocalBroadcastManager` has been deprecated. This sort of "event bus" pattern for internal communications within a process is considered by some to be a poor programming practice.

> What or who is sending these intents then? Could it be done by the user itself?

Sure. Attackers gonna attack. It could be via `adb shell`, or via some custom app the attacker wrote, or perhaps via some automated security scanning app.

Do not use IPC (`registerReceiver()` on `Context`) for communications within an app's process.

Comment: Thanks, great. I've added some additional information on if LocalBroadcastManager should be used to the OP.

Comment: @Michiel: "It's packaged within androidx and at the moment not labeled as deprecated." -- it has been marked as deprecated for months. See [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager) and [the library page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/localbroadcastmanager).

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'll look into a better replacement for it.